# How to work out the equation for surface to volume ratio?

Tags: geometry, volume

I want to work out the equation for volume of half a sphere against the surface area of the circle at the widest part of the sphere.

The equation of the half sphere is (2/3) * (pi * r ^3), where r is the radius, and obviously the area of the circle is pi *(r ^2).

Basically I want a function like: surface area = (something) * (volume ^ something) + something.

Any hints would be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume of a hemisphere is $V=\frac 23 \pi r^3$ and as you say the area of a circle is $A=\pi r^2$  You can't have a direct proportion between them as the units do not match.  As $r$ increases, the volume increases faster than the area.  What you can have is $V=kA^{3/2}$ or $A=k'V^{2/3}$  If you plug in the formulas for $V,A$ you can evaluate $k,k'$.

Comment: Thanks @RossMillikan that worked. Problem solved!